# Merge sort with raw C++ array

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

Merge function:

```
void merge(int outputArray[], int firstArray[], int sizeFirst, int secondArray[], int sizeSecond){
    int p = 0;
    int p1 = 0; 
    int p2 = 0;
    while(p1 < sizeFirst && p2 < sizeSecond){
        if(first[p1] < second[p2])
            outputArray[p++] = firstArray[p1++];
        else 
            outputArray[p++] = secondArray[p2++];
    }

    while(p1 < sizeFirst) outputArray[p++] = firstArray[p1++];
    while(p2 < sizeSecond) outputArray[p++] = secondArray[p2++];
}
```

Sort function:

```
void sort(int numbers[], int size){
    if(size == 1) return;
    int mid = size/2;
    int firstPartSize = mid;
    int secondPartSize = size - mid;

    int firstArray[firstPartSize];
    int secondArray[secondPartSize];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ;i++){
        if(i < mid)
            firstArray[i] = numbers[i];
        else 
            secondArray[i - mid] = numbers[i];
    }

    sort(firstArray, firstPartSize);
    sort(secondArray, secondPartSize);
    merge(numbers, first, firstPartSize, second, secondPartSize);
}
```

Personally I think the number of arguments in the merge function are bit too many. I considered making a different function that calculates size of the array but that didn't seem to work with my current knowledge of the language.

1. Should I care about readability in standard algorithms?
2. What other names would you suggest instead of `p`, `p1`, `p2` so that readability is not hampered?
3. Are there any other bugs or problems with the code?

Answer (score 4):

With regards to variable names and readability, I would recommend the following:

- Change `p` to `outputIndex`
- Change `p1` to `firstIndex`
- Change `p2` to `secondIndex`
- Change `sizeFirst` to `firstSize`
- Change `sizeSecond` to `secondSize`

Comment: Thanks! could you elaborate more on the last two variable names?

Comment: @nashmaniac: I just figured that you might as well use "first" and "second" as prefix in **all** variable names (and not as prefix in some of them and as posfix in others).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @nashmaniac: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

- The most important property of a merge sort is stability: elements comparing equal maintain the original order. A condition

  ```
  if(first[p1] < second[p2])
  ```

  destabilizes the algorithm. It shall read

  ```
  if(first[p1] <= second[p2])
  ```
- Replace the final `while` loops with `std::copy`.
- Split the copy loop into two:

  ```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < mid ;i++) {
      firstArray[i] = numbers[i];
  }

  for (int i = mid ; i < size ;i++) {
      secondArray[i - mid] = numbers[i];
  }
  ```

  Then replace them with two calls to `std::copy`.

Comment: I thought of that, then figured that the else clause takes care of the "=" case. Am I missing something? Initially I had two separate for loops but then merged them into one for brevity. Was that a wrong decision? Why? I wasn't aware of std:: copy, thanks for mentioning, that is something to learn.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the splitting part. Please ignore latter part of the comment above.

Comment: The else clause takes wrong care: according to your code, of two equal elements, one from the _second_ array is copied first. The original order is thus broken. Re merged loops: with loops merged you need to evaluate a (totally redundant) condition on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not allow run time array sizing in the standard language:

```
int firstArray[firstPartSize];
int secondArray[secondPartSize];
```

Though it is provided as an extension in some compilers.
But you should really use `std::vector` here.

```
std::vector<int> firstArray(firstPartSize);
std::vector<int> secondArray(secondPartSize);
```

I am not sure if this has been updated in the later language extensions (C++11/C++14 would be grateful if somebody could comment with standard info).

The other thing about your solution is that it uses \$O(n^2)\$ space. This algorithm can be done in \$O(n)\$ space. So there is some work to be done there.

Comment: No arrays of runtime bound (aka variable-length arrays) up to and including C++14.

Comment: @dyp: NO. Variable length arrays were not part of C++03. They were introduced into C99 but never taken on as part of C++. I know there was a lot of discussion of adding them to C++11 but I am not sure of the resolution and will need proof in the form of a standard quote (or a reliable blog post from somebody reliable Stroustrup/Alexandrescu/Sutter/Meyers). Now C++14 I could believe much more easily but would need a standard quote. Now a lot of compiler accepted them because (C and C++ compilers are closely intertwined) but only as a non standard extension.

Comment: OK. Variable length arrays were not in C++11 either. And they were remvoed from C++14 before release. But there is an alternative called `std::dynarray` which allocates locally and has a fixed size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303902/any-alternative-to-stddynarray-presently-available/17344395#17344395

Comment: I'm not sure how you interpreted my comment, what I wanted to say is "there are no arrays of runtime bound in C++, neither in C++98, nor C++03, nor C++11, nor C++14"

Comment: @dyp: Yes I did interpret that incorrectly. Sorry.